# error in arraylist sorting using collections.sort()

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, comparator, greedy

I am writing a code on fractional knapsack. But, the sorting algorithm is not working well. And hence my code is not working correctly.

This is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
class Item {
    int profit, weight;
    float ppw;
    //ppw is profit per weight
    public Item(int profit, int weight) {
        this.profit = profit;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.ppw= (float)profit / (float)weight;
    }
}

class SortbyPPW implements Comparator\<Item\> {
    public int compare(Item o1, Item o2) {
        return (int) (o2.ppw) - (int) (o1.ppw);  
    }
}

public class FractionalKnapSack {
    public static void main(String args\[\]) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the number of elements: ");
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter maximum capacity: ");
    int capacity = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("\\nEnter the items with their profit and weight separated by a space");

    ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int profit = sc.nextInt();
        int weight = sc.nextInt();
        items.add(new Item(profit, weight));
    }

    System.out.println("\n");
    for (Item item : items)
        System.out.print(item.ppw+" ");
    System.out.println("\n");


    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(items.toArray()));
    double[] maxValue = getMaxValue(items, capacity);
    System.out.println("\nMaximum profit we can obtain = " + maxValue[0]);
    System.out.println("Capacity Used = " + (capacity-maxValue[1]));
    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(items.toArray()));

    System.out.println("\n");
    for (Item item : items)
        System.out.print(item.ppw+" ");
    System.out.println("\n");
}

public static double[] getMaxValue(ArrayList<Item> items, int capacity) {
    double maxValue = 0;
    Collections.sort(items, new SortbyPPW());

    for (Item item : items) {
        int currWeight = item.weight;
        int currValue = item.profit;

        if (capacity - currWeight >= 0) {
            capacity -= currWeight;
            maxValue += currValue;
        } else {
            double fraction = ((double) capacity / (double) currWeight);
            maxValue += (currValue * fraction);
            capacity = (int) (capacity - (currWeight * fraction));
            break;
        }
    }
    double[] arr1={maxValue, (double)capacity} ;
    return arr1;
}
```

}

I tried using simple array instead of arraylist and it worked correctly but my teacher wants to code to have collections.sort() and comparator class implemented.
This is the input
8
40
20 10
30 15
18 5
25 12
14 6
24 8
15 7
10 3

Expected Output
103.91
Actual Output
100.0

[Input and Output on my laptop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqKO6.png)

But, my code here got close only upto 100 and thus it's not correct completely.

Comment: [Do not show pictures of text](/help/how-to-ask), just put the actual text in your post, in [code fences](/markdown). Also, look at your post after submitting: you have things in your code that are guaranteed not in your actual code.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried using simple array instead of arraylist and it worked correctly

I find that hard to believe.  The `Comparator` you created is deficient, whether used with an array or with a `List`.

You are sorting based on `Item.ppw`, which is a `float`.  There's nothing inherently wrong with that, but consider your specific implementation:

```
        return (int) (o2.ppw) - (int) (o1.ppw);
```

If `o1.ppw` and `o2.ppw` are different, but `(int) o1.ppw` and `(int) o2.ppw` are the same, then the wrong result (`0`) will be returned.

I'm inclined to guess that you tried to adapt a more subtly flawed yet relatively common implementation for `int`-based comparisons.  Using a difference of two `int`s as the return value of a comparator is more right than your code, but it will still produce the wrong answer if the subtraction overflows.

Don't try to be so clever.  A `Comparator` of this general form is perfectly good for comparing objects by any single field of primitive type:

```
class CompareByPPW implements Comparator<Item> {
    public int compare(Item o1, Item o2) {
        if (o1.ppw < o2.ppw) {
            return -1;
        } else if (o2.ppw < o1.ppw) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Or simply `return Float.compare(o1.ppw, o2.ppw);`